# How do i set dynamic rating bar view in AlertDialog?

Tags: android

First it runs smooth but when i click on it again it stops

I got error on trying to set dynamic rating bar view in `AlertDialog`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
 rtb = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ratingbar_dialog, null);
    rb = (RatingBar) rtb.findViewById(R.id.rtbDialog);

    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    ad.setView(rtb);

    ll1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ad.setMessage("Rate Price");

            ad.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ad.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    rtbPrice.setRating(rb.getRating());
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inflate the `view`. .
Set the xml via `setContentView()` and access the `rating bar` via  `FindviewbyId()`

Answer (score 2):

Because each time you call `ad.show()`, a new dialog will be created and the same view `rtb` will be added as dialog content (So the 1st time works, then exception was raise in the 2nd time).
To fix it:

- you can move all the code from `inflate` to `setView` into the `onClick` method
- OR inside `onClick`, remove `rtb` from it's parent: 
  `if (rtb.getParent() instanceOf ViewGroup) { ((ViewGroup)
  rtb.getParent()).removeView(rtb); }`
- OR refactor your code to let it's only create and show one dialog.